# SparkSession null point exception in Dataset foreach

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark.

I want to keep getting message from kafka, and then save to S3 once the message size over 100000.

I implemented it by Dataset.collectAsList(), but it throw error with `Total size of serialized results of 3 tasks (1389.3 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize`

So I turned to use foreach, and it said null point exception when used SparkSession to createDataFrame.

Any idea about it? Thanks.

---Code---

```
SparkSession spark = generateSparkSession();
        registerUdf4AddPartition(spark);
        Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", args[0])
                .option("kafka.group.id", args[1])
                .option("subscribe", args[2])
                .option("kafka.security.protocol", SecurityProtocol.SASL_PLAINTEXT.name)
                .load();
        DataStreamWriter<Row> console = dataset.toDF().writeStream().foreachBatch((rawDataset, time) -> {
            Dataset<Row> rowDataset = rawDataset.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)");
            //using foreach
            rowDataset.foreach(row -> {
                List<Span> rawDataList = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new StringReader(row.getString(0))).withType(Span.class).build().parse();
                spans.addAll(rawDataList);
                batchSave(spark);
            });

            // using collectAsList
            List<Row> rows = rowDataset.collectAsList();
            for (Row row : rows) {
                List<Span> rawDataList = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new StringReader(row.getString(0))).withType(Span.class).build().parse();
                spans.addAll(rawDataList);
                batchSave(spark);
            }
        });
        StreamingQuery start = console.start();
        start.awaitTermination();

public static void batchSave(SparkSession spark){
        synchronized (spans){
            if(spans.size() == 100000){
                System.out.println(spans.isEmpty());
                Dataset<Row> spanDataSet = spark.createDataFrame(spans, Span.class);
                Dataset<Row> finalResult = addCustomizedTimeByUdf(spanDataSet);

                StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder("s3a://fwk-dataplatform-np/datalake/log/FWK/ART2/test/leftAndRight");
                finalResult.repartition(1).write().partitionBy("year","month","day","hour").format("csv").mode("append").save(pathBuilder.toString());
                spans.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the main `SparkSession` is running in **driver**, and tasks in `foreach...` is running distributed in **executors**, so the `spark` is not defined to all other executors.

BTW, there is no meaning to use `synchronized` inside `foreach` task since everything is distributed.

Comment: so there is no way to use ```spark``` to create ```dataframe``` when in ```foreah```? May you advise if any idea for my requirement? ```consume message from kafka and save once message size over 100000```

Comment: 1. you can define anything (include `SparkSession`) in executor as in the driver ; 2. why you need to spill/slice data every 100000 messages ?

Comment: As I said, my spark job will keep continue  consuming message, if I dont control the file size, the file will be too large

Comment: you may take a look this official doc  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators ; and maybe you need to check if it's possible to append data in s3 service